# In SQLAlchemy, group_by on column property no longer works in 1.0.0b1

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

A change from 0.9.9 to 1.0.0b1 in the query functionality is causing me some heartburn.  I have a group_by clause that uses a `column_property`.

In 0.9.9, the generated query reproduces the calculated value in GROUP BY by actually calculating the value again.  In 1.0.0b1, the calculation is wrapped in an anon_1, and MSSQL won't let you group_by a named value for a calculated field.

Is there some way to revert to the old behavior without requiring a specific version?

**The below code generates the following SQL in 0.9.9:**

```
SELECT 
    count(cdr_extended.[UniqueID]) AS [CallCount],
    sum(cdr_extended.[Duration]) AS [TotalSeconds], 
    ext_map.[FName] + ' ' + ext_map.[LName] AS anon_1 
FROM cdr_extended, ext_map 
WHERE 
    (ext_map.exten = cdr_extended.[Extension] 
        OR ext_map.prev_exten = cdr_extended.[Extension]) 
    AND cdr_extended.[StartTime] > '2015-01-01' 
    AND cdr_extended.[Extension] IN ('8297') 
GROUP BY ext_map.[FName] + ' ' + ext_map.[LName]
DESC
```

**However, in 1.0.0, it produces this code**:

```
SELECT 
    count(cdr_extended.[UniqueID]) AS [CallCount],
    sum(cdr_extended.[Duration]) AS [TotalSeconds], 
    ext_map.[FName] + ' ' + ext_map.[LName] AS anon_1 
FROM cdr_extended, ext_map 
WHERE 
    (ext_map.exten = cdr_extended.[Extension] 
        OR ext_map.prev_exten = cdr_extended.[Extension]) 
    AND cdr_extended.[StartTime] > '2015-01-01' 
    AND cdr_extended.[Extension] IN ('8297') 
GROUP BY anon_1 
DESC
```

**Here's the model:**

```
class EMap(Base):
    FName = Column(String(length=45))
    LName = Column(String(length=45))
    AssociateName = column_property(FName + " " + LName)
```

**The code in question:**

```
   DBSession.query(func.count(ExtendedCDR.UniqueID)
.label("CallCount"),func.sum(ExtendedCDR.Duration)
.label("TotalSeconds"))
.filter(or_(ExtensionMap.exten == ExtendedCDR.Extension,ExtensionMap.prev_exten == ExtendedCDR.Extension))
.filter(ExtendedCDR.StartTime>jan1)
.filter(ExtendedCDR.Extension.in_(extensions))
.group_by(ExtensionMap.AssociateName)
.order_by(func.count(ExtendedCDR.UniqueID).desc())
```

**And finally, here's the actual stack trace when the group_by fails:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_exclog-0.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid_exclog/__init__.py", line 111, in exclog_tween
    return handler(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 163, in handle_request
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 245, in _secured_view
    return view(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 355, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 501, in _requestonly_view
    response = view(request)
  File "/opt/cedar/cedar/views/ViewMyDashboard.py", line 51, in MyDashboardView
    YearList = ObstinateDatabaseQueryAll(DBSession.query(func.count(ExtendedCDR.UniqueID).label("CallCount"),func.sum(ExtendedCDR.Duration).label("TotalSeconds"),ExtensionMap.AssociateName).filter(or_(ExtensionMap.exten == ExtendedCDR.Extension,ExtensionMap.prev_exten == ExtendedCDR.Extension)).filter(ExtendedCDR.StartTime>year_today).filter(ExtendedCDR.Extension.in_(extensions)).group_by(ExtensionMap.AssociateName).order_by(func.count(ExtendedCDR.UniqueID).desc()))
  File "/opt/cedar/cedar/controllers/db.py", line 40, in ObstinateDatabaseQueryAll
    ret=query.all()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2408, in all
    return list(self)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2525, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2540, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1332, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 442, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S22', "[42S22] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'anon_1'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: 'SELECT count(cdr_extended.[UniqueID]) AS [CallCount], sum(cdr_extended.[Duration]) AS [TotalSeconds], ext_map.[FName] + ? + ext_map.[LName] AS anon_1 \nFROM cdr_extended, ext_map \nWHERE (ext_map.exten = cdr_extended.[Extension] OR ext_map.prev_exten = cdr_extended.[Extension]) AND cdr_extended.[StartTime] > ? AND cdr_extended.[Extension] IN (?) GROUP BY anon_1 ORDER BY count(cdr_extended.[UniqueID]) DESC'] [parameters: (' ', datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0), '8297')]
```

Comment: FWIW: Release 1.0.0 is still a beta release - so you might want to submit this as a bug/issue: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: Added an issue: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3338/change-from-099-to-100b1-introduces-syntax

Comment: the developers have acknowledged this as a critical bug.  When it is fixed I'll answer the question for completeness' sake.

Comment: looks like it got resolved https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3338/change-from-099-to-100b1-introduces-syntax

Comment: thanks @kristi, I answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was identified as a bug by the developer and the fix for it will be published in the 1.0.0b4 milestone.